# MPICH-p4 alternative to -nolocal flag

Tags: mpi, mpich

Is there an alternative for the `-nolocal` option when I run an MPI program using mpiexec of MPICH-p4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is run all of your processes locally, don't provide a hostfile (or provide one that only includes localhost). Keep in mind that you're severely limiting how much parallelization you can do to essentially the number of cores you have. After that, you start to oversubscribe them and you can run out of resources quickly.

Comment: What -nolocal does is making the new processes to run only on the remote machines and making only the main program to be executed on the local machine isn't it?

Comment: Not the main program, just the launcher for MPI. All of your ranks will execute on the other hosts in your hostfile.